# Google Email Api Modify lable

Tags: c#, google-api, google-oauth, gmail-api, google-api-dotnet-client

Trying to modify a label.

My code:

```
service.Users.Messages.Modify(mods, userId, messageId).Execute();
```

Error message:

> The service gmail has thrown an exception: Google.GoogleApiException: Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
>   Insufficient Permission [403]
>   Errors [
>       Message[Insufficient Permission] Location[ - ] Reason[insufficientPermissions] Domain[global]
>   ]
>
> at Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest`1.Execute() in C:\Apiary\v1.25\Src\Support\GoogleApis\Apis\Requests\ClientServiceRequest.cs:line 101
>      at CreditRecon.DownloadAttachment.ModifyMessage(GmailService service, String userId, String messageId, List`1

Answer (score 0):

In order to update a users messages you need the permission of the user.

> Insufficient Permission

Means that you do not have the permission of the authenticated user modify their messages.

Re-authenticate your user and make sure you have requested one of the following scopes of permissions from them

> https://mail.google.com/ 
>   https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify

**Update reauthencate user:**

To reset authentication change  "shankitagrawal@ltfs.com" to something else. or go into your credPath and delete the file with that as its name.  It will prompt you to authenticate again.

Comment: How to Re-authenticate the user. i am using this https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/modify

Comment: Check your authentication code you should have something like "user"  change that.   If you dont understand please edit your question and add your auth code.

Comment: GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                        GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                        { GmailService.Scope.GmailLabels,GmailService.Scope.MailGoogleCom },
                        "shankitagrawal@ltfs.com",
                        CancellationToken.None,
                        new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;

Comment: less secure apps need to be given permission.

Comment: @ShankitAgrawal check my update that should help you reauthncate

Comment: This is due to organization level (G Suite Admin) security which restricts third party application to modify mails. It allows only read-only access.